# deleting content of a file excepting comments using .bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a .properties file which is of the format

```
####
#These are the comments
####

this is the content
```

I want to delete every thing except the comments of this file.

Comment: Do I understand correct? You want to keep the comments and delete the content? (sorry for asking back, but this seems quite unusual) Does every comment start at the start of the line?

Comment: yes, comments are only at the start of the files and I can say, 10 lines at the start are comments, so  have to delete all the content after 10 lines

Comment: Strange... but ok. Npocmaka's answer should work fine for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
findstr /b "#" "properties.properties" >new.properties
```

try this.

Comment: answer is a great help but is there a way I can do it using `properties.properties` only

Comment: @viveksinghggits you can add a line that moves `new.properties` to the old file: `move /y new.properties properties.properties`

Comment: thank you, is there an online source or your blog where can I find some tutorials on this.

Comment: Trick that don't require another file: `(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /B "#" "properties.properties" ^& del "properties.properties"') do echo %%a) >> "properties.properties"`